# Have one part of a query update based on another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not looking for a specific answer to a question so much as a general direction of what to look for when doing further research.  I have a query which is very useful and a certain aspect, `mytable.column1` I frequently change.  Depending on what `mytable.column1` is, there is an alias in the table that I would like to change as well.  So, if `mytable.column1` is 1 the alias needs to be something like `aliasFor1`, if it's two, then the alias needs to be `aliasFor2`.  What is the nomenclature for doing something such as this, and what are some good resources for reading up on it?

Comment: So the 'alias' column to be updated is based on the value of `column1`?  What happens if that alias column doesn't exist - like if the value is set to 543, or are you sure this won't be allowed to happen?

Comment: @PinnyM that wouldn't be allowed to happen.  Ideally, there is a column `mytable.column2` which would supply the alias based on what `mytable.column1` was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (if I am right). Also covered [here - Creating Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
create table computed
(
    column1 int, 
    descr as 'aliasFor'+CAST(column1 as varchar))
)
```

Everytime you update `column1`, the other column also get updated.

### [See it happen in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cc93/1)

Comment: never heard of computed tables before, i'll read about it, thanks.

Comment: this isn't exactly what i needed, but it was exactly what i asked for.  thanks, now i have more of an idea of what i need to look for.